# WCF streaming mode is really slow

Tags: wcf, streaming

I want to know why WCF in streaming mode is really slow compared to the buffered mode.

Basically, I'm reading a lot of data from a server (database access) then transferring that huge data through WCF to other clients.

I was doing some tests and benchmarks by comparing the 2 different transfer modes.

I created 2 endpoints. The first one is using `transferMode="Buffered"` and the other one is using `transferMode="StreamedResponse"`.

By loading the same 1 millions rows from a SQL server (Dummy table), here are the results:

- Buffered: **20447** milliseconds.
- Streaming: **109417** milliseconds.

The streaming is done like in that [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52083534/1504370). Basically, the data is stored in an `IEnumerable<T>` and then streamed to the client that consumes it.

I can provide the WCF `app.config` files if needed.

By the way, I already had a look on other similar questions like those:

[WCF NetTcpBinding Buffered vs Streamed performance problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2111844/1504370)

But they don't really give an appropriate answer.